# async await a Promise and get the returned boolean from 'then' and 'catch'

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I'm trying a make a function which returns boolean to whether an Adblock is detected or not. The module I'm using `@horat1us/detect-ad-block` is a `Promise` which returns values through their `then` and `catch`. How can I use the `async` and `await` to wait until a boolean value is retrieved? I have researched a lot but I'm still not able to figure it out. I'm still not able to understand `async` and `await`. Any help would be great. Thanks.

`adblock.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { DetectAdBlock } from "@horat1us/detect-ad-block";
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/@horat1us/detect-ad-block

async function ads_check() {
    return await DetectAdBlock().perform({ timeout: 15000 })
    .then((result: boolean): boolean => {
        return result;
    }).catch((error: any): boolean => {
        return error ? true : false;
    });
}

export default class AdBlock extends React.Component<any, any> {

    componentDidMount(): void {
        console.log("A");
        console.log(ads_check() ? "AdBlock Detected" : "AdBlock Not Found");
        console.log("B");
    }

    render() { return (null); }
}
```

Comment: Check this for better understanding : https://javascript.info/async-await#:~:text=If%20await%20gets%20a%20non,then%20proceeds%20with%20the%20result.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi How can I get the [[PromiseValue]]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) **always** returns a promise, you have to call `.then` or use `await` when you call `ads_check()`, you can't resolve a promise in a different function and then just call the function like it's synchronous.

Also, you don't need to make `ads_check` async and just do `return DetectAdBlock()`, It's redundant to use `return await` when you don't catch the error and return something else/log/rethrow inside a `try/catch` block.

```
async componentDidMount(): void {
  console.log("A");
  console.log(await ads_check() ? "AdBlock Detected" : "AdBlock Not Found");
  console.log("B");
}
```

or

```
componentDidMount(): void {
  console.log("A");
  ads_check().then(result => {
    console.log(result ? "AdBlock Detected" : "AdBlock Not Found");
  })
  // this console.log will run before the promise resolve
  console.log("B");
}
```